# Source for "na rudro rudramarchathi"

Tags: rudra, rudram

I came across the following statement while reading a book

> Narudro Rudramarchathi

The book says its meaning as follows

> A person who is not Rudra cannot do Archana for Rudra

The book is saying that **rudram** is the name of the source. Where can I find that Rudram scripture **that contains the given statement**?